# WooCommerce: Stop scrolling to error message on checkout page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Usually WooCommerce scrolls to `.form.checkout` if there is an error on the checkout form. I want this to stop because it somehow interferes with ScrollMagic.js.

If I don't enqueue ScrollMagic.js everything is working fine, but with ScrollMagic.js enabled the page just jumps a bit to the top.

I tried to use `$(document.body).on('checkout_error', function () { $( 'html, body' ).stop(); }` but it doesn't work.

If I use

```
$(document.body).on('checkout_error', function () {
    // There was a validation error
    console.log('checkout_error triggered');
});
```

There are no log messages in the console. Why isn't there anything happening? How can I stop the WooCommerce animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now my console logs are appearing. I didn't change anything at all, but `jQuery('html, body').stop();` doesn't trigger.

But by using GSAP ScrollToPlugin I can now scroll to the `ul.woocommerce-error` using

```
$(document.body).on('checkout_error', function () {
  TweenLite.to(window, 1, {scrollTo:"ul.woocommerce-error"});
  console.log('checkout_error triggered');
});
```

as described here: https://greensock.com/ScrollToPlugin.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this article](https://frique.me/blog/prevent-automatic-scrolling-to-checkout-error-in-woocommerce/) you could try this?

```
jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete( function() {
    if ( jQuery( 'body' ).hasClass( 'woocommerce-checkout' ) || jQuery( 'body' ).hasClass( 'woocommerce-cart' ) ) {
        jQuery( 'html, body' ).stop();
    }
} );
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work either. Somehow jQuery(html, body').stop(); doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's really old topic but I found much easier solution. Just edit 3 notice templates (error.php, notice.php, success.php) and remove role="alert" and that's it. The scroll funciton won't find element to scroll to.

Edit:

I can confirm this works! You find these templates under wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/notices/

If you don't already have a WooCommerce override directory inside your theme, you need to create a folder called woocommerce inside your theme, and copy the notices directory and it's contents there. Then edit each of those .php template files as stated above.

Comment: could you be more specific please?

Comment: I like this solution. It looks like only success.php has the role="alert" in it these day, but just overriding that template still seemed to do the trick somehow.